# Вызов @endpoint по http внутри сервера

Tags: java, servlet, rest, backend

В API приложения выделено 2  ресурса  /app/A  и /app/B  ( замаплены  на соответствующие Java сервлеты).   /app/A   вызывает /app/B
Каким образом  оптимальнее организовать взаимодействие по http , чтобы ресурс /app/B   мог быть вызван только другими сервлетами, если  идет обращение с клиента нужно возвращать  403 Forbidden.